# How to show a javascript confirmation box on "WordPress menu" before leaving the website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, menuitem

I wants to show a javascript message box when a user clicks on a "FORUM" link on WordPress menu.

The message box should show a message like "You are leaving this website..." and **once the user confirms the message box, it should open an external link in a new tab.**

[I had tried this](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm), but it will fire the message box, when ever I leave the website or reload the page. I just wants this message box on a single WordPress menu item.

I saw some tutorials to do this, but not able to do it on WordPress menu.

WordPress does not recognize `javascript:void(0)` or any other javascript function on URL part.

Any ideas??

Comment: Do you have access to the FORUM element? Can you just bind a click event to it?

Comment: @Aesthete, WordPress menu items are dynamically generating with PHP codes. We have the built-in menu editor. But javascript functions cannot be entered there.

Comment: :Offtopic: Don't do it, Its the fastest way to annoy your users! (not to mention me)

Comment: I know its annoying, but client need it. :)

Comment: Do the generated menu items have unique ids or classes?

Comment: yes it has unique id. `#menu-item-82`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it working. I'm explaining it step by step, so someone with similar issue can solve this:

1. Put `#` in your wordpress menu url  in which you want the JavaScript
   Function.
2. Track this menu url (li ID) link from source code. in my case li id
   is `menu-item-88`. (this id is auto generated by wordpress and
   always unique)
3. Place the following code before the end of head tag (open header.php
   find `</head>`) of current theme.
4. Don't forget to change the menu-id `menu-item-88` to yours.

`<script type="text/javascript">`

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var menuID = jQuery('#menu-item-82');

findA = menuID.find('a');

findA.click(function(event){
if(confirm("YOU ARE LEAVING THE WEBSITE" + '\n' + "" + '\n' + "You are about to leaving the website to go to the external forum" + '\n' + "" + '\n' + "The FORUM will open in a new tab")) 
{
window.open('http://www.yourforum.com/','_blank'); //This will open the website in a new tab
}

});
});
</script>
```

This requires jQuery. So if jQuery is not loaded, add the following line also to your head.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This will prompt you that, you are leaving the website. If you clicks OK, it will open the given link in a new tab.

Ok. Thats all.. This will do the magic.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have jQuery loaded?
Where is the forum link?
Where's the code?

```
<a href="http://www.yourforum.com" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to leave?');" />
```

Comment: Yeah. Jquery is loaded. I know this can be done if you are using plain html. But WordPress menu items are dynamically generating with PHP codes. The built-in menu editor will not support any javascript functions.

Comment: Just tested this, works a treat.

@Libin just find the template file /php file and edit it manually.

Comment: @Waltzy, No buddy. Its not like what you think. WordPress will dynamically loads the menu from database. `<?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>` Displays a navigation menu created in the Appearance → Menus panel. So it is not possible to edit it manually.

Comment: @Libin if you can set the link destination you could try somthing like this: `javascript: return (confirm('Are you sure you want to leave?'): window.location="http://www.yourforum.com" ? false );`

Comment: @Libin, Just tested this you will need to something like in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set the link location to something like this:

```
javascript: if (confirm('Are you sure you want to leave?')) {window.open('http://www.yourforum.com','_blank');}
```

which should generate html like:

```
<a href="javascript: if (confirm('Are you sure you want to leave?')) {window.open('http://www.yourforum.com','_blank');}">Link</a>
```

I tested this in JS fiddle, seems to work, so you should be able to put this as the link location in your database.

Edit:

```
// for a new tab
window.open(url,'_blank');
// for a redirect in same window
window.location=url;
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help.. But my bad luck, its all about WordPress. Can't do this directly. Anyway I will seek the help of WordPress experts from http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Aye, but im guessing you can set the url of menu links? so where you would usually put that, put that line starting `javascript:blablabla` instead

Comment: Yes I can set the url of menu. I tried it. But wordpress does not recognize javascript:void(0) or any other javascript function. It simply filter it out for additional security..

Comment: Thanks for all your help dude. Answered it myself. Thanks for giving the code to open a link on new window. :) +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add any javascript to your page, anywhere, you can do the following (Needs jQuery, but you said you have that loaded):

```
$("a[href='http://example.com/forum']").click(function() {
    alert("Good bye!");
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer dude. I got a spark from this. :) Answered it myself. +1 for you. :)